# Most common verbs

Tags: verbos, conjugación

I am a spanish learner and I figured out that I **really** need to learn the verbs. Is there a good (preferably online) resource with let's say the 100 most common verbs and conjugation to get me started.

Comment: [Another discussion in this site](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/323/list-of-most-commonly-used-spanish-words) may be useful to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Well the most important verbs in Spanish may be:

A quick search in google gives this [**link 1**](http://www.lingolex.com/comveren.htm) which states to give the list of the 100 most used verbs in Spanish. The verbs included are very common, but it's difficult to say if they are the most common or not. Anyway I'd point out that important verbs like these ones are missing in that list:

- **Haber** (for compound tenses)
- **Ser** (to be)
- **Estar** (to be)

These 3 verbs though are not included in the previous link are basic for Spanish.

This other links: [**link 2**](http://www.linguasorb.com/learnspanish/most-common-verbs.aspx) and [**link 3**](http://www.sipuebla.com/verbos/100verbs.htm) are in my opinion betterbecause they include those verbs too.

If you want to see the conjugation of any of those verbs you can go to the website of **[RAE](http://www.rae.es/)** (the official institution for the Spanish language). You can go to that link and put the verb in the box which is called "Diccionario de la lengua española". After pressing "enter" you'll be given the definition of the verb and before the verb there is a button called "**Conjugar**". If you press it you'll see the conjugation of that verb.

RAE also has some lists of most frequent words [**here**](http://corpus.rae.es/lfrecuencias.html), but they are not only verbs.